# Pixi js - Loader doesnt reach progress of 100%

Tags: loader, pixi.js

I am using the PIXI.Loader to load images for sprites.
Therefore I am tracking the loading progress to show and hide a corresponding loader component.
When the progress is at 100 the loader component is set to invisible.

So far this was working totally fine, but suddenly the loader stops at 99.99999999999984%.
The images seem to be loaded all correctly, but the loader components obviously won't hide.

I am using React, the part where the progress is looks like the following:

```
if (loader && !firstRender.current) {
    firstRender.current = true
    loader.onProgress.add(l => {
        setProgress(l.progress)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (progress === 100) setVisibility("none")
}, [progress])

return (
    <div className="bg" style={{display: visibility}}>
        <CircularProgressWithLabel color="primary" value={progress} />
    </div>
)
```

Does anybody have an idea why the progress doesn't reach 100%?

Kind regards
Philipp

Comment: This seems to be float number problem which exists in javascript and also in other languages. (example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript  ) . Can you paste a snippet showing how you use said "loader" ?

Comment: @domis86 Thanks for the tip already. I've added a snipped.

Comment: Maybe I will just use ```.toFixed(10)``` as a workaround.

Comment: Yes, such rounding should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 loader.onComplete.add(() => {
  this.loadingComplete();
});
```

and then do your processing by defining

```
  loadingComplete(){//your stuff}
```

method whith whatever you want to do after loading is complete. worked for me perfectly